# Como puedo obtener los num. del array mas grandes y igual al valor que yo introduzco?

Tags: java

```
public double[] ejercicio4(double[] b){
    Vector<Double> tmp = new Vector<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < tmp.size(); j++)
        {
            if(tmp.get(j).doubleValue() == b[i])
                found = true;
        }
        if(!found)
            tmp.add(b[i]);
    }
    double rat[] = new double[tmp.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++)
    {
        rat[i] = tmp.get(i);
    }
    return rat;
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    double[] arraybro = {3, -5, 2.4, 0, 17};
    double[] b = ejercicio4(arraybro);
    Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Introduzca un numero: ");
    System.out.print("{3, -5, 2.4, 0, -5, 17, 3}    ----->    ");
    for(int i=0;i<arraybro.length;i=i+2){
        int aux;
        if(arraybro[i]<arraybro[i+2]){
            aux=(int) arraybro[i+2];
            arraybro[i+2]=arraybro[i];
            arraybro[i]=aux;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola lethal, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. No está muy claro lo que necesitas. Explica mejor lo que pretendes y tu situacion actual. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Pregunta: ¿por qué asignas double[] b = ejercicio4(arraybro); si luego "b" no la usas para nada?

Comment: es para llamar a la classe

Comment: ¿A qué clase? No termino de enteder qué estás intentado hacer

Comment: a la classe ejercicio4

Comment: `ejercicio4` no es una clase, sino un metodo. Lo que @Kiko_L menciona es que el resultado de llamar a ese metodo no lo utilizas. Tampoco utilizas la entrada del usuario, debes tratar de explicar bien tu problema y las dudas que tienes

Comment: No esta muy claro lo que preguntas, por favor, puedes [edit] la pregunta y aclarar que es lo que necesitas y que es lo que hace tu programa

Comment: El resultado es el valor que yo he introducido se imprima por pantalla los valores de array mas cercanos      ej:   array:{1,2,3,4}                                valor introducido:2 ------->  resultado:{2,3,4}

Comment: Lethal, por favor edita la pregunta **incluso aunque hayas encontrado respuesta**. Mira mi comentario y los enlaces. Asi como está la pregunta se cerrará como "no está claro lo que se pregunta"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Fijate si esto es lo que buscabas:

```
public class Test
{
    public static double[] ejercicio4(double[] a, double value)
    {
        //
        // Primero eliminar los repetidos
        //
        Vector<Double> tmp = new Vector<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            boolean found = false;
            for(int j = 0; j < tmp.size(); j++)
            {
                if(tmp.get(j).doubleValue() == a[i])
                    found = true;
            }
            if(!found)
                tmp.add(a[i]);
        }
        //
        // Buscar el los valores superiores o igual al valor determinado
        //
        if(tmp.size() > 0)
        {
            Vector<Double> max = new Vector<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++)
            {
                double x = tmp.get(i).doubleValue();
                if(x >= value)
                    max.add(x);
            }
            tmp = max;
        }
        //
        // Transformar a array
        //
        double ret[] = new double[tmp.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++)
        {
            ret[i] = tmp.get(i);
        }
        return ret;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] arraybro = {3, -5, 2.4, 0, 17};
        System.out.print("Introduzca un numero: ");
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        double[] b = ejercicio4(arraybro, lector.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("{3, -5, 2.4, 0, -5, 17, 3}    ----->    ");

        System.out.print("{");
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
        {
            if(i != 0)
                System.out.print(", ");
            System.out.print(b[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Germán. Gracias por aportar, sin embargo, no siempre ha de responderse a preguntas. La pregunta ha de ser de calidad y clara. Lo recomendable es esperar a que se edite la pregunta para contestar. Además , las respuestas han de ir con la explicación de lo que fallaba al usuario y como tu respuesta lo soluciona. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Hola, al contestar tu intención es buena pero por lo que se ve este problema es un ejercicio para etapa escolar o pre-universitaria, esta clase de ejercicios permiten desarrollar las habilidades de un estudiante para resolver problemas, al tratar de ayudarles estamos perjudicando su desarrollo, ademas de que esta clase de preguntas solo benefician a una persona y no son de utilidad a la comunidad de StackOverflow, saludos.